Need formula to get uniques values where raw data in on cell with comma separated format
In F column, I have a list of audience in comma separated format in which audience are repeated more than one time
In google sheet, I need formula in G2 Cell to get unique audience id from F2 cell which are comma separated format

In google sheet, I need formula in G2 Cell to get unique audience id from F2 cell which are comma separated format


You may use-
=TEXTJOIN(",",1,UNIQUE(TOCOL(SPLIT(F2,","),1)))



Here's an array formula that you can try:
=ArrayFormula(LET(data,A2:A4,
                  splitData,SPLIT(data,","),
                  rowTot,ROWS(splitData),
                  colTot,COLUMNS(splitData),
                  numList,SEQUENCE(rowTot,colTot,0),
                  colNum,MOD(numList,colTot),
                  rowNum,QUOTIENT(numList,colTot),
                  instance,COUNTIFS(splitData,splitData,colNum,"<="&colNum,rowNum,rowNum),
                  removeDup,IF(instance=1,splitData,),
                  reConcat,TRANSPOSE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(removeDup),,9^9))," ",",")),
                  reConcat))



shorter arrayformula:
=IFERROR(BYROW(A1:A, LAMBDA(r, JOIN(",", UNIQUE(TOCOL(SPLIT(r, ","), 1))))))


